# how to set Array as default value in react select

Tags: reactjs

I'm using mui select. I set the value [array type], but am unable to set the default value.

```
<select
  defaultValue={[181, 182, 183]}
  onChange={(e) => {
    Setselectedverticle(e.target.value);
  }}
>
  <MenuItem key={0} value={0}>
    Select the Verticle
  </MenuItem>
  {verticle.map((e, i) => {
    return (
      <MenuItem key={i} value={e.value}>
        {e.label}
      </MenuItem>
    );
  })}
</Select>;
```

I listed the sample data format below.

```
VERTICLE
    [{key:184
    label:"Entertainment"
    value:[185, 186, 187, 188]},
    {key:185
    label:"Entertainment"
    value:[185, 189, 189]}]
```

Comment: Are you using a `select` element or some `Select` component? Can you include a more complete [mcve] so we've more context around this code snippet.

Comment: When you use onChange you need to use value instead of defaultValue and the you can initialise the useState([181, 182, 183]);

Comment: Just pass value property to your Select tag with the key value of the element, and save the array elements in a separate element as default element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use value instead of defaultvalue

```
<select
      Value={[181, 182, 183]}
      onChange={(e) => {
        Setselectedverticle(e.target.value);
      }}
    >
      <MenuItem key={0} value={0}>
        Select the Verticle
      </MenuItem>
      {verticle.map((e, i) => {
        return (
          <MenuItem key={i} value={e.value}>
            {e.label}
          </MenuItem>
        );
      })}
    </Select>;
```